# Passing in list elements in javascript to a different function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do a web scraping exercise where some values are being retrieved and are being stored in a list variable. I am then passing in the list variable as a parameter in a different function. The problem with my approach is I am getting an error when calling the different function. I believe I'm getting this error because I am not passing in the list elements into the function appropriately. In the function, I am reading from a Yahoo Stock API used to retrieve stock data. If I were to hardcode a stock symbol into the parameter for the function, it works without any issue. Since I am passing in a parameter, I am getting this error. Below is my code and the error I am getting. Any feedback would be helpful.

**Code**

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');
const yahooStockPrices = require('yahoo-stock-prices');

var stockSymbol = []
async function read_fortune_500() {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios({ method: "GET", url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies", })
    const $ = cheerio.load(data)
    const elemSelector = '#constituents > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)'

    $(elemSelector).each((parentIndex, parentElem) => {
      let keyIndex = 0
      if (parentIndex <= 9){
      $(parentElem).children().each((childIndex, childElem) => {
        const tdValue = $(childElem).text()

        if (tdValue) {
          //stockObject[keys[keyIndex]] = tdValue
          stockSymbol = tdValue
        }
      })
      console.log(stockSymbol)
    }
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
  return stockSymbol;
}

async function collect_stocks(stockSymbol) {
  stockSymbol = read_fortune_500()
  const stockResult = await yahooStockPrices.getCurrentData(stockSymbol);
  console.log(stockResult);
}

collect_stocks(stockSymbol)
```

**Error**

```
/node_modules/yahoo-stock-prices/yahoo-stock-prices.js:75
                .split('regularMarketPrice')[1]
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at Request._callback (/node_modules/yahoo-stock-prices/yahoo-stock-prices.js:75:21)
    at Request.self.callback (/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Request.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Request.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
```

Comment: Did you plan to call `read_fortune_500()`?

Comment: If I can avoid not calling that function, it would be best. I've tested that function, and it works.

Comment: The point is that you're calling `collect_stocks(stockSymbol)` with `stockSymbol=[]`, at least as your code is presented right now.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter stockSymbol seems to be empty when you pass it to your desired function therefore, when yahoo-stock-prices try to apply a split on it, it fails.

Comment: Yeah I see that. When I run the first function, read_from_fortune_500, it returns values and displays it to the console what each value. Not sure why when calling the second function it reads as empty.

Comment: Then you probably want to assign the return value of read_fortune_500 to stockSymbol :

stockSymbol = read_fortune_500();
collect_stocks(stockSymbol);

Your functions are at a similar scope but the scope is not common to both, the variable stockSymbol remains [] when you exit your function read_fortune_500()

Comment: Here is some usefull documentation about scope in JS.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Yeah I came across that as well. I changed the stockSymbol variable from "let" to "var" since the "let" does not allow values to change. Still getting the same error however.

Comment: That's not a problem of let / var. 


What you assign to stockSymbol in read_fortune_500() is not saved.
You can :
- pass stockSymbol as a param of read_fortune_500()
OR
- get the return value of read_fortune_500() and stock it in stockSymbol
OR
- use context and 'this' to manipulate variables in functions sharing the context scope
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I'm still missing something and getting the same error. I'll update the code

Comment: When you print stockSymbol in your first function, does it contain someting ? console.log(stockSymbol)

You want stockSymbol to contain only one value ?